# Scrollable container with columns and overflow-y: auto

Tags: html, css

I want to make a scrollable container whose content is laid out in columns.  I am finding that I cannot use the property `column-count` together with `overflow-y: auto` and a fixed size on the same element.  The content always overflows horizontally, making more columns than what I have specified in `column-count`.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>   
</ul>

<ul class="with-columns">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>  
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 5px;
  background: coral;
  margin: 2px;
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
}

li:nth-child(2n+3) {
  height: 90px; /* simulate variable height content  items */
}

ul {
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

ul.with-columns {
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 0;
}
```

How can I make `ul.with-columns` vertically scrollable without wrapping it in an additional element?

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/gegawidayi/4/edit

Answer (score 2):

I think what you might want to do instead is set max-height instead of the height on ul.

```
ul {
    background: lightblue;
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

This should give you what you're looking for.